# Getting OTA update once phone is rooted

Tags: root-access, ota-update, 5.0-lollipop

My nexus 4 is rooted with a team win recovery.

In the past week I've been asked three times to update to lollipop, downloaded the update but all three times the phone rebooted and the custom teammwin recovery failed to install the update...

I'm afraid having rooted my nexus makes it ineligible to official updates. Could you confirm it?

Do I need to come back to stock rom & recovery, then install OTA update and root it again (seems like a long process and possible memory wipe?)

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just reinstall the official recovery image by downloading the same [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) as currently running and extracting the recovery.img that's contained within.

Then you could reinstall the official recovery image by booting into fastboot mode and doing an:

```
    fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

This should give you back a working OTA mechanism. However note that you need to re-root after the update because this will undo the rooting procedure.

Comment: I am on a rooted android 10 phone ( magisk) . I restored stock recovery. No Luck OTA's keep failing. I then restored stock Boot after removing magisk . Still got veriification error. My BL is unlocked. What does it take to get my OTA zip file working.... do I `flash dm verify force encrypt` . Why does it refuse. Should `BL` be locked as well

Answer (score 0):

Did it say something like "Books.apk has unexpected contents"? If you've modified or removed system apps, just reflash system, install ota and reboot. The data partition AFAIK doesn't get wiped; with my moto g it didn't. Note that you will need to download the same version as you have on your phone, that version is shown in "system version"

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier, i wasn't home since... I finally reflashed a stock 5.0 image with the nexus root toolkit and it worked like a charm. I've read somewhere else that a rooted devices was unlikely to receive an OTA update since a check of the installed recovery was made before install. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Bertrand I meant that you should download the version you had, not lollipop and use the OTA when provided, but the way you did it works just as well :D

Comment: I am on a rooted android 10 phone ( magisk) . I restored stock recovery. No Luck OTA's keep failing. I then restored stock Boot after removing magisk . Still got veriification error. My BL is unlocked. What does it take to get my OTA zip file working.... do I flash dm verify force encrypt . Why does it refuse. Should BL be locked as well